# Tuning process exited unexpectedly. (DTAEngine)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, database-tuning-advisor

I know there is the same question, but I'm running it on a different version and still have the issue.

I was running the DTA from the GUI - workload source was Query Store and I ran the analysis against a single table.
After about 30 minutes in, I get this non-descriptive error:

> Tuning process exited unexpectedly. (DTAEngine)

I've tried it several times, always with the same results.
In msdb, only these 3 tables have some rows in them, but nothing useful

```
SELECT * FROM DTA_reports  
SELECT * FROM DTA_input  
SELECT * FROM DTA_progress
```

Is there anything I can do to debug the issue and make it work?
In previous questions, I read I need to be a member of the sysadmin role, which I am.

Version information:

> Database Engine Tuning Advisor                     15.0.18369.0

> Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU10) (KB5001090) - 15.0.4123.1 (X64)
> Mar 22 2021 18:10:24
> Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
> Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Where do you get that error message from? What about SQL Server log, is there any other error around the time that process fail? Can you use XE to capture more details of the error?

Comment: The error is in the DTA GUI - there is an ongoing log that shows which steps are currently processed. Nothing in the SQL Server log or in XE (error_reported)

Comment: Is the problem happening for any table you run the analysis against or just one specific table?

Comment: I'm interested in just the one, so I didn't test. But I am looking for a generic way how to get a more specific message than just "it broke".